# My KMZ works for older versions of GE, but not the newer ones

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

I have a KMZ file which is a time animation. It used to work in the older GE, such as version 5 (I think). I can load the KMZ file in the newer GE, but do not see the animation control bar to play it. Something needs to be changed in the KMZ file, but cannot figure out. Here is the beginning and end of the KML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
<Folder>
  <name maxLines="1">ADCIRC_pbl</name>
  <Snippet maxLines="1"><![CDATA[]]>
  </Snippet>
  <Folder><name><![CDATA[ahframe_legend]]></name><visibility>1</visibility><ScreenOverlay><visibility>1</visibility><overlayXY x="1" y="1" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" /><screenXY x="1" y="1" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" /><Icon><href>ahframe_legend.png</href></Icon></ScreenOverlay></Folder>
<Folder>
<name maxLines="1">ahframe_1: Image</name>
  <Snippet maxLines="1"><![CDATA[]]>
  </Snippet>
  <GroundOverlay>
    <TimeSpan>
        <begin>2005-08-28T23:00:00z</begin>
        <end>2005-08-28T23:30:00z</end>
    </TimeSpan>
    <name maxLines="1">ahframe_1</name>
    <Icon>
      <href>ahframe_1.png</href>
      <viewBoundScale>1.0</viewBoundScale>
    </Icon>
    <LatLonBox>
      <north>30.46</north>
      <south>29.44</south> 
      <east>-88.3531</east>
      <west>-89.6952</west>
       <rotation>0</rotation> 
     </LatLonBox>
   </GroundOverlay> 
 </Folder>
<Folder>
<name maxLines="1">ahframe_2: Image</name>
  <Snippet maxLines="1"><![CDATA[]]>
  </Snippet>
  <GroundOverlay>
    <TimeSpan>
        <begin>2005-08-28T23:30:00z</begin>
        <end>2005-08-29T00:00:00z</end>
    </TimeSpan>
    <name maxLines="1">ahframe_2</name>
    <Icon>
      <href>ahframe_2.png</href>
      <viewBoundScale>1.0</viewBoundScale>
    </Icon>
    <LatLonBox>
      <north>30.46</north>
      <south>29.44</south> 
      <east>-88.3531</east>
      <west>-89.6952</west>
       <rotation>0</rotation> 
     </LatLonBox>
   </GroundOverlay> 
 </Folder>
<Folder>
```

The KML file ends like this:

```
<name maxLines="1">ahframe_77: Image</name>
  <Snippet maxLines="1"><![CDATA[]]>
  </Snippet>
  <GroundOverlay>
    <TimeSpan>
        <begin>2005-08-30T13:00:00z</begin>
        <end>2005-08-30T13:30:00z</end>
    </TimeSpan>
    <name maxLines="1">ahframe_77</name>
    <Icon>
      <href>ahframe_77.png</href>
      <viewBoundScale>1.0</viewBoundScale>
    </Icon>
    <LatLonBox>
      <north>30.46</north>
      <south>29.44</south> 
      <east>-88.3531</east>
      <west>-89.6952</west>
       <rotation>0</rotation> 
     </LatLonBox>
   </GroundOverlay> 
 </Folder>
 </Folder>
 </kml>
```

Comment: Which version have you tested it on?

Comment: 7.0.1.8244 (beta)

Comment: Could you make the whole file available somewhere? That may make your question much easier to answer. Consider using one of: DropBox, Google Drive, SmartBins

Answer (score 3):

So far I came up with this: 
I replaced the first 2 lines of the original KML with the following 3 lines:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
    xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
```

Then I replaced the lower case "z" of the Timespan by uppercase "Z", like these:

```
    <TimeSpan>
      <begin>2005-08-28T23:00:00Z</begin>
      <end>2005-08-28T23:30:00Z</end>
    </TimeSpan>
```

That seem to have solved my problem. Now the time slider is visible. Who knew!

Answer (score 0):

Did you click the time slider button?
[time slider on YouTube](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=time%20slider%20button%20google%20earth&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDYQtwIwAg&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jt40eoevCVc&autoplay=1&ei=znWxUPjCLK2A2QW8uYDIDg&usg=AFQjCNFjvdtjsevmhm0q-b7umi_azCd70w&sig2=3RKQJhLnXlXuO2C8GypcMg)

Comment: I do not have the time slider button to click on. This is what I am missing. It used to come automatically in the older GE version.

Comment: @Akbar you need to post this answer and mark it as the answer.